# Nested components in Angular CLI not accessible after first level

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm new in Angular CLI and I'm trying to make my first web based on an older one I've made.
Until now, I'm able to nest and show components inside the root component, but from that point onwards I can't refer to any component in the HTML.

Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Testing Angular</title>
      <base href="/">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, FirstComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<section id="container">
  <app-first></app-first>
</section>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**first.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SecondComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class FirstModule { }
```

**first.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./first.component.css"]
})

export class FirstComponent {}
```

**first.component.html**

```
<div id="first">
  <app-second></app-second> <!-- This gives an error: it doesn't know whats Second Component -->
</div>
```

**second.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class SecondModule { }
```

**second.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./second.component.css"]
})

export class SecondComponent {}
```

**second.component.html**

```
<div id="second">
  <span>I'm second component!</span>
</div>
```

The `<app-second></app-second>` reference gives an error. In Visual Studio Code is not even in the list of suggestions.

Comment: You should import FirstModule in AppModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include your modules somewhere, angular don't know anything about your SecondComponent, add FirstModule or SecondModule to your AppModule.
Take a look at Angular docs to get more strategies https://angular.io/docs

```
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FirstModule],
```

Modify your FirstModule with adding exports with components which you want to share for others modules.

```
exports: [SecondComponent]
```

Comment: I thought about that, and I tried, but still can't refer to SecondComponent in FirstComponent html.
Also, I think that including Components will automatically include Modules, since they are related.

Comment: Forgot:) add export: [Second Component] to your FirstModule

Comment: It works! Add the export part to the answer so I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Great! Updated with exports array